# Google Analytics Language Codes

Tags: google-analytics, report, analytics, country

Need help with Google Analytics filters via Custom Reports -- Display LANGUAGE and VISITS where the LANGUAGE values are grouped as EN for each English, etc via 'FlatTable'

**My report returns (see first 3 lines):**

```
LANGUAGE | VISITS
---------+-------
en-us    | 55,842
en       | 3,932
en_us    | 248
```

**I would like to see:**

```
LANGUAGE | VISITS
---------------------+----------+-------
 1. en   | 60,022
 2. ...
 3. ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a **Custom Dimension** to store an extracted part from the *Language Setting* dimension via an [Advanced Filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830).

That way you will **extend your data** instead of replacing parts of it.

1. Create a Dimension *LanguageCode* with scope *User* or *Session* in the property's settings (Admin > Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions)
2. Create an advanced filter *Extract Language Code* in the view's filter settings (Admin > View > Filter) like so:

   - Field A: *Language Settings* `([a-z]{1,3}).*`
   - Output in: *Language* (the Custom Dimension) `$A1`

Be aware that filters get applied during processing, which happens once a day. That means you'll be able to see the result the next day.

Then you'll be able to view reports or build a custom report that uses that new *Language Code* dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, go to Custom Reports and set one up like this:
[image]

Then, go and to the newly created report and apply a secondary dimension of Language. If you want to 'group' them by language, do a sort by Language.

I add Language to the dimension drilldown so if you were interested in seeing the possible language selection for a particular country you could do that by clicking on the country.

Comment: I revised the question, because of an error. Please note that I found some info on http://www.gliffy.com/blog/2012/07/31/more-useful-browser-statistics-from-google-analytics-using-filters/

Comment: I also saw more info at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en

Comment: If you would never have a need for anything that comes after the first two letters you could create a new profile and apply a search and replace filter to the language settings field.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics Admin create an additional view to the property. Then create two custom filters:

1. Name (e.g. Language lowercase): Lowercase -> Filter Field: Language
   Settings;
2. Name (e.g. Language generalisation): Search and Replace ->
   Filter Field: Language Settings : Search string: `([a-z]{1,3})[-_]?.*` Replace string: `\1`

That is it. Now all languages in the view will be up to 3 character long and aggregated.

Actually the regex can be more strong, but this one is more wide and covers even some wrong language settings.

Comment: Pay attention, since this will overwrite the original _language settings_ dimension.